# Using Box2d bodies for infinite scrolling

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, scroll, box2d

I am making a game using cocos2d and box2d that basically consists of a ball rolling down an infinite hill.  My current approach consists of using CCFollow to create the scrolling effect, while iterating through a series of four background images to create continuity.  I want the ball to bounce of the hill, so I considered making the hill from two b2Body objects that alternate one another.  But this requires manually moving the bodies, which seems to make keeping track of the placement of the corresponding sprite somewhat confusing. Should the hill images even be sprites?  Is there a better approach that makes this easier?

Comment: What is the exact shape of the hill ? is it a rotated box  ? you should specify more details as it is hard to answer from the general description

Comment: you probably need more than two bodies. But your approach should work fine.

Comment: For the shape, all I need is a line where the slope should be.  But I can't figure out how to set the shape as a line.  If I did do that, how would Box2D specify the position of the body?  Is it by the midpoint of the line?